# fullcalendar. eventOrder one by one like stairs

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it real to make/move/sort events like [stairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4tUB.png)?
Because it's look more logical in my case

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own custom view, or modify one of the existing view's codes. Not a simple task. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/ Also think of the wasted space for users on smaller screens.

Alternatively if these events are all taking place in different locations you could use the Scheduler plugin, which each event inside a different Resource, to get the visual effect. But this is a commercial plugin you have to pay for, unless you work for a charity or open-source project. https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/